# Why doesn't Mathematica completely draw the fit?

Tags: fitting, data, modeling

I have a question, and I really need your help, because I think I'm not understanding the reason...

I have a potential model..

```
F[x_] := k x^n
```

for the next graphic...

[image]

the fits shows a error and it doens't draw the curve completly...

> NonlinearModelFit::sszero: The step size in the search has become less than the tolerance prescribed by the PrecisionGoal option, but the gradient is larger than the tolerance specified by the AccuracyGoal option. There is a possibility that the method has stalled at a point that is not a local minimum.

```
data2={{0.000205, 81.41}, {0.000422, 58.14}, {0.00144, 30.51}, {0.00198,25.93}, {0.00396, 18.98}, {0.00485, 16.83}}
```

and and I used this...

```
FindFit[data2, F[x], {k, n}, x]
```

Comment: Provide the code (copy and paste form) and the **data** that you used.

Comment: try using explicit plot range: `Plot[Evaluate[F[x] /. FindFit[data2, F[x], {k, n}, x]], {x, 0, .006}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, .006}, {0, 90}}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point@data2}]`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the option  `PlotRange` (say `PlotRange -> {{0, .006}, {0, 90}}`), and

use `data2` as [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html):

```
Plot[Evaluate[F[x] /. FindFit[data2, F[x], {k, n}, x]], {x, 0, .006}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, .006}, {0, 90}}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point@data2}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use `Plot` first in `Show`:

```
Show[Plot[Evaluate[F[x] /. FindFit[data2, F[x], {k, n}, x]], {x, 0, .006}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, .006}, {0, 90}}], 
 ListPlot[data2, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]]]
```

> same picture

Comment: thanks a lot @kglr, it was very helpfull :)

Comment: @ChrisSchwenke, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.